# How to select a last row - Column1 Value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

How to select a last row - Column1 Value in SQL

I cant use Orderby .. As i dont have ID Column !!

Just want to pick most last row .. first column ..

select top 1 [FileName] from PlacedOrderDetails  - But from Last Row ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An SQL table is an unordered set.  It does not, by default, contain information about the order in which records were created.  So you have to explain to SQL Server what you mean by "first record".  The way to do that is an `order by` clause.

If you just want any record, you can use a randomized order using the `newid` function:

```
select top 1 * from YourTable order by newid()
```

Comment: select top 1 * from YourTable order by newid()   - This query gives First Row .. I am looking for Last Row

Comment: Then you need to define what "last row" means

Comment: @Chok: `newid()` returns a random number; so the query will return a random row, not the first or last one.  As I tried to explain in the answer, a table is an unordered set.  It has no "first" or "last" row unless you order them.  Compare it to a bowl of M&M's: how would you retrieve the "first" M&M ?

Comment: OP does not want ANY row. OP wants last row inserted in DB. That's what @Chok calls last. Your post does no really answer OP's question

Comment: @Adrian: The answer explains that SQL Server does not store the order in which records were created.  That means SQL Server does not know which row is the last row.  You cannot retrieve it.  "Impossible" is a valid answer at times :)

Comment: Now there's an answer: it's impossible. You should add that to the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

This won't help with existing records, but if you want to track this from now on, you can add a column that automatically stores when the record was inserted:

```
ALTER TABLE PlacedOrderDetails ADD [DateTimeCreated] DateTime DEFAULT (GetDate())
```

Then just select the record with the most recent value for that column:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM PlacedOrderDetails ORDER BY DateTimeCreated DESC
```

Comment: kELLEY DUDE ../. I DONT HAVE ID OR DATE COLUMN .. THATS A BASIC KNOWLEDGE .. TO ORDER BY DATE OR ID

Comment: @Chok – Perhaps you should have that, considering your requirement.

Comment: WELL, I AM DIGGING INTO A THIRD PARTY DATABASE .. FOR WHICH MY APP IS PULLING ..!! WE HAVE NO RIGHTS TO MODIFY THEIR DB -

Comment: @Chok – Ok, that makes things a bit difficult. BTW, I think you have accidentally pressed the CAPS LOCK key. You are using nothing but capital letters when writing.